# in C#.net, Can i pass a DataContext object (created by LINQ to SQL) as a parameter of a method in another class?

Tags: linq-to-sql

in C#.net, Can i pass a DataContext object (created by LINQ to SQL) as a parameter of a method in another class ?

Comment: Why?? You really shouldn't be passing around stuff like DataContexts - grab the data you need into a List<SomethingOrAnother> and then pass that list to another method....

Answer (score 2):

You can if the project that the class is defined in references the project the dataContext object is created in.

Those DataContext objects are auto-generated however and aren't necessary a good dependency to add to your other "concrete" classes.

I'd just translate the data in the dataContext into a concrete business object and pass that it into your class as a parameter to your method.

Answer (score 0):

The DataContext is just reference to your model interface. Passing it as a reference is useless since you can instantiate it whenever you want and this approach would even confuse other developers.

"First of all, passing a ref variable is used to be able to change variable that holds the reference. But since you are not changing the DataContext dbase reference in your GetPByRole method, passing it as a ref is useless and would even confuse other developers. Perhaps you misunderstand value types and reference types. Reference types (such as DataContext) are always passed by reference, passing it around through method calls will not make new copies of the object itself, merely copies of the reference (which is a 32 or 64 bits value)."

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5248024/5878893